# Получение данных связанных таблиц

Tags: php, laravel

Существует ли в laravel 8.0 способ получения данных из связанных таблиц? В C# есть entityframework, который позволяет это реализовать. Что я имею ввиду: получая данные из таблицы servers, например, с id 1, получать данные из таблицы filters уже в преобразованном виде. Схему базы данных прикладываю.
[image: Схема базы данных]

Comment: Ну через отношения, да...

Comment: [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: @Simon спасибо, это действительно помогло мне!